# Review of Suggested Edits. Review-Beta: It is not easy to determine difference between original post and edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review

In some cases, for example when only the message's format was changed, it is not easy to determine what the difference is between an original post and a new potential text.

Maybe it would be better to have the possibility, before decision-making, to view both texts in 'raw' mode (like in 'Edit' mode of a question or answer).

Another example when the 'raw viewing mode' can help is the case when the user has made a mistake in a message format and as a result some piece of text or image is invisible.

Now I cannot check the format of the original post and sometimes it is impossible to take a right decision "to accept the edit or not".

***Update***

I'm talking about ***Review - Suggested Edits*** tool at ***review-beta***.

I've attached two images to illustrate the issue.

The first review mode is not allowed me to check the original post.

[image: The first mode of review]

And the same for the second mode. This is even worse - the code's block is gone.

[image: The second mode of review]

I'm not able to view the format of the code's block, for example.

Comment: Sorry can't see any problem. The user [suggesting the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/341646) just added four spaces, blank line and one sentence. Both modes show the difference, in the first you have to scroll down to see it and the second shows only things that were changed. The code block was not changed thus not displayed in the "markdown diffs" mode. Typical case of invalid edit. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The text may contains an incorrect format, and as a result the image (or the code block) from the post can be invisible. The editor corrected the message and as result the image (or the code block) will be appeared. But for me (as a reviewer) it is unclear - is it a new image (and in this case it will invalid edit) or is it a correct edit. Is it clear now?

Comment: Such changes are always visible, e.g. removed image will have red border and new image will have green border. Code formatting is always visible in the markdown diffs mode - if such exist. In your case the user just wrote "improved formatting" he could also write "I made this to an awesome post". It means nothing. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No, I'm talking about the case when the original post was damaged (because of wrong format). The "good" guy correct the post and the new piece is appeared (this piece was invisible). But reviewer can't see the original post in 'draw' format (formatting, markup). May be the editor was the 'bad guy'... I'll try to make the understandable screenshot to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When reviewing you can already select to see the actual markdown comparison of the two revisions by selecting the second view icon on the left. There you can switch between rendered view, markdown view or get the link to the specific suggested edit.

[image: And this got approved...sigh]